# Android, make a rather complicated animation?

Tags: android, animation

I know how to make a typical animation using `Animation` API in Android. But I don't know how to make this:

[image: A sample of the animation]

It is simply a `textview` inside a ring while the ring is animating and the `textview` is just in a fix state. Note that the ring thickness is not changing while scaling.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have your ring as a view already, you simply create an AnimatorSet with two ObjectAnimators that changes the scaleX and scaleY of the ring view. How far to scale depends on how far you want the ring to extend out or in.

Make sure you set the pivotX and pivotY to be the center of the view.

Then, simply have it repeat.

Comment: Thanks @Jackey . I need the ring thickness stay fix when it is scaling up and down! In the way you mentioned its thickness would change.